# Selenium webdriver with Dataprovider run each test with null parameter

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have created few tests by using selenium, TestNG with dataprovider.
When i run the test each time test gets executed twice one with parameter and second with null parameter  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRH2H.png)

[Please find screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8HG2.png)

Please let me know how to fix the issue.

Appreciate your help!!

Code:
public class AppTest_BlankOrder 
    extends ReplaceBaseclass
{

```
CreatePageLocator pf;

public AppTest_Blankrder()
{}


/* Below code is used to open the browser....*/
@BeforeTest
public void testSetup() {


    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./testdata/chromedriver.exe");
    driver= new ChromeDriver();

     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(500, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.get("http://loginapp.group/");


}

    @Test(dataProvider="WosLoginData",dataProviderClass=CreateProvider.class,priority = 1)
    public void WOSLogintest(String user,String password)
    { 

        System.out.println("Open Logintest method and pass data");


        // -----page factory code---
    CreatePageLocator pf= new CreatePageLocator(driver);

        pf.setUserName(user);

        pf.setPassword(password);

        pf.clickLogin();

    }
```

//---- Data provider code----

```
public class CreatePageProvider {
@DataProvider(name="WosLoginData")
public Object [][] getLoginData(Method name)
{
    Object [][] data=null;
    /
    ExcelDataConfig config=new com.ExcelDataConfig("./testdata/InputData.xlsx");
    int rows=config.getRowCount(0);

                data=new  Object[rows][2];

    for(int i=1; i<rows; i++)
    {
        data[i][0]=config.getData(0, i, 0);
        data[i][1]=config.getData(0, i, 1);



    }


enter code here
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Add the relevant code also...

Comment: @Grasshopper - Added code

Comment: can't see the dataprovider class code

Comment: @niharika_neo - Added dataprovide class code

Answer (score 0):

The counter of the for loop in the dataprovider should start at **0**. This is what is making the first element of data[][] to have null values.

Comment: @Grasshopper- Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Grasshopper- Actually i am reading second row data of excel sheet in data provided, excell fist row is header with USERNAME and PASSWORD due to this i have started loop at 1. Is there any other way to read excel cell data using data provider to avoid null values issue.

Comment: Then use -- data[i-1][0] and data[i-1][1] when you are placing values into the 2 dimensional array

Comment: @Grasshopper- I would be really helpful if you share some sample code.